# Skia C++ VS2015 project setup

Tags: visual-studio-2015, skia

I'm trying to create a simple windows application using Skia and C++ on visual Studio 2015. I *believe* I have created static, shared and release versions of skia.lib, and have linked to the proper include folders. But now I still get many errors, which suggests there's a bigger problem than merely linking. I have tried copying the configuration properties from the working HelloWorld project in the Skia solution to my own, but have not had any success.

Are there any definitive instructions for getting Skia to work with VS2015 once the lib has been produced? If not, why would I be getting (many and varied) problems when trying to use Skia in bare template win32 projects? Is there a better way to copy properties from one project to another?

I'm relatively new to VS and C++. I'm using VS2015 and C++ because other parts of a bigger project I'm working towards seem to require this platform. So I guess what I am trying to do is make a *standalone* Skia 'hello world' example.

There is some frustration about building Skia for VS2015/7. Here's how I managed what I had, shared in the hope that it may help someone else make some progress as well as shed light on my current problem.

- The Git package in Depot Tools does not appear to be sufficient. So installed Git For Windows before Depot_tools.
- Build Tools for Visual Studio 2017 is required, even though the target in this case is VS 2015.
- Followed the Depot_tools installation instructions to "TL;DR".
- Followed the Skia set up instructions as far as "python tools/git-sync-deps"
- Rather than using the arguments supplied by the instructions created skia/out/ folders as follows:

  ```
  bin\gn gen out/Static --ide=vs2015 --args="is_official_build=true"

  bin\gn gen out/Shared --ide=vs2015 --args="is_official_build=true is_component_build=true"

  bin\gn gen out/Debug --ide=vs2015

  bin\gn gen out/Release --ide=vs2015 --args="is_debug=false"
  ```
- Running "ninja -C out/[Shared/Static/Release/Debug]" seems doomed to fail, as the paths seem not to have been created properly by gn. Instead, opened the sln in each /out/* in VS2015. Then found the 'skia' project and built it. (Also built the pathkit project)
- This created skia.lib (and pathkit.lib) in Static, Shared and Release, but the Debug version didn't work.
- Other instructions for VS in the Skia documentation simply do not work. e.g. "python infra/bots/assets/win_toolchain/download.py -t C:/toolchain" and/or "python infra/bots/assets/win_toolchain_2015/download.py -t C:/toolchain". Perhaps this may cause later problems. However, the included HelloWorld project does compile and run successfully this way.

In reply to Hans, below, here are the errors generated by attempting to build the /out/Release solution.

---

```
Error   MSB3073 The command "call ninja.exe -C ../../../../../out/Release/  obj/modules/sksg/samples.stamp" exited with code 1. samples ((skia)\(modules)\(sksg)\samples)   C:\Users\Me\Documents\skia\out\Release\obj\modules\sksg\samples.vcxproj 64  
Error   MSB3073 The command "call ninja.exe -C ../../../../../out/Release/  ./sksg.lib" exited with code 1. sksg    C:\Users\Me\Documents\skia\out\Release\obj\modules\sksg\sksg.vcxproj    160 
Error   MSB3073 The command "call ninja.exe -C ../../../../../out/Release/  obj/modules/skottie/tool.stamp" exited with code 1. tool    C:\Users\Me\Documents\skia\out\Release\obj\modules\skottie\tool.vcxproj 64  
Error   C1083   Cannot open compiler generated file: 'C:\Users\Me\Documents\skia\out\Release\obj\src\gpu\effects\gpu.GrOvalEffect.obj': Permission denied   skottie C:\Users\Me\Documents\skia\src\gpu\effects\GrOvalEffect.cpp 1   
Error   MSB3073 The command "call ninja.exe -C ../../../../../out/Release/  obj/modules/skottie/skottie.stamp" exited with code 1.  skottie C:\Users\Me\Documents\skia\out\Release\obj\modules\skottie\skottie.vcxproj  108 
Error   MSB3073 The command "call ninja.exe -C ../../../out/Release/  ./lua_pictures.exe" exited with code 1.   lua_pictures    C:\Users\Me\Documents\skia\out\Release\obj\lua_pictures.vcxproj 66  
Error   C1083   Cannot open compiler generated file: 'C:\Users\Me\Documents\skia\out\Release\obj\src\sksl\gpu.SkSLMetalCodeGenerator.obj': Permission denied    skshaper    C:\Users\Me\Documents\skia\src\sksl\SkSLMetalCodeGenerator.cpp  1   
Error   MSB3073 The command "call ninja.exe -C ../../../../../out/Release/  obj/modules/skshaper/skshaper.stamp" exited with code 1.    skshaper    C:\Users\Me\Documents\skia\out\Release\obj\modules\skshaper\skshaper.vcxproj    64  
Error   C1083   Cannot open compiler generated file: 'C:\Users\Me\Documents\skia\out\Release\obj\src\gpu\text\gpu.GrGlyphCache.obj': Permission denied  pathops_unittest    C:\Users\Me\Documents\skia\src\gpu\text\GrGlyphCache.cpp    1   
Error   MSB3073 The command "call ninja.exe -C ../../../out/Release/  ./pathops_unittest.exe" exited with code 1.   pathops_unittest    C:\Users\Me\Documents\skia\out\Release\obj\pathops_unittest.vcxproj 290 
Error   C1083   Cannot open compiler generated file: 'C:\Users\Me\Documents\skia\out\Release\obj\src\sksl\gpu.SkSLParser.obj': Permission denied    public_headers_warnings_check   C:\Users\Me\Documents\skia\src\sksl\SkSLParser.cpp  1   
Error   MSB3073 The command "call ninja.exe -C ../../../out/Release/  obj/public_headers_warnings_check.stamp" exited with code 1.  public_headers_warnings_check   C:\Users\Me\Documents\skia\out\Release\obj\public_headers_warnings_check.vcxproj    64  
Error   C1083   Cannot open compiler generated file: 'C:\Users\Me\Documents\skia\out\Release\obj\src\effects\effects.SkTrimPathEffect.obj': Permission denied   sk_app  C:\Users\Me\Documents\skia\src\effects\SkTrimPathEffect.cpp 1   
Error   C1083   Cannot open compiler generated file: 'C:\Users\Me\Documents\skia\out\Release\obj\src\gpu\gl\gpu.GrGLGLSL.obj': Permission denied    nanoMech    C:\Users\Me\Documents\skia\src\gpu\gl\GrGLGLSL.cpp  1   
Error   MSB3073 The command "call ninja.exe -C ../../../out/Release/  obj/sk_app.stamp" exited with code 1. sk_app  C:\Users\Me\Documents\skia\out\Release\obj\sk_app.vcxproj   88  
Error   MSB3073 The command "call ninja.exe -C ../../../out/Release/  ./nanoMech.exe" exited with code 1.   nanoMech    C:\Users\Me\Documents\skia\out\Release\obj\nanoMech.vcxproj 66  
Error   C1083   Cannot open compiler generated file: 'C:\Users\Me\Documents\skia\out\Release\obj\src\pdf\pdf.SkPDFUtils.obj': Permission denied skia    C:\Users\Me\Documents\skia\src\pdf\SkPDFUtils.cpp   1   
Error   MSB3073 The command "call ninja.exe -C ../../../out/Release/  ./skia.lib" exited with code 1.   skia    C:\Users\Me\Documents\skia\out\Release\obj\skia.vcxproj 1690    
Error       opening build log: Permission denied    skp_parser  C:\Users\Me\Documents\skia\out\Release\obj\ninja    1   
Error   MSB3073 The command "call ninja.exe -C ../../../out/Release/  ./skp_parser.exe" exited with code 1. skp_parser  C:\Users\Me\Documents\skia\out\Release\obj\skp_parser.vcxproj   66  
Error       opening build log: Permission denied    skpMech C:\Users\Me\Documents\skia\out\Release\obj\ninja    1   
Error   MSB3073 The command "call ninja.exe -C ../../../out/Release/  ./skpMech.exe" exited with code 1.    skpMech C:\Users\Me\Documents\skia\out\Release\obj\skpMech.vcxproj  66  
Error       opening build log: Permission denied    skpinfo C:\Users\Me\Documents\skia\out\Release\obj\ninja    1   
Error   MSB3073 The command "call ninja.exe -C ../../../out/Release/  ./skpinfo.exe" exited with code 1.    skpinfo C:\Users\Me\Documents\skia\out\Release\obj\skpinfo.vcxproj  66  
Error       opening build log: Permission denied    sktexttopdf C:\Users\Me\Documents\skia\out\Release\obj\ninja    1   
Error   MSB3073 The command "call ninja.exe -C ../../../out/Release/  ./sktexttopdf.exe" exited with code 1.    sktexttopdf C:\Users\Me\Documents\skia\out\Release\obj\sktexttopdf.vcxproj  66  
Error       opening build log: Permission denied    sse2    C:\Users\Me\Documents\skia\out\Release\obj\ninja    1   
Error   MSB3073 The command "call ninja.exe -C ../../../out/Release/  obj/sse2.stamp" exited with code 1.   sse2    C:\Users\Me\Documents\skia\out\Release\obj\sse2.vcxproj 75  
Error       opening build log: Permission denied    sse41   C:\Users\Me\Documents\skia\out\Release\obj\ninja    1   
Error   MSB3073 The command "call ninja.exe -C ../../../out/Release/  obj/sse41.stamp" exited with code 1.  sse41   C:\Users\Me\Documents\skia\out\Release\obj\sse41.vcxproj    64  
Error       opening build log: Permission denied    sse42   C:\Users\Me\Documents\skia\out\Release\obj\ninja    1   
Error   MSB3073 The command "call ninja.exe -C ../../../out/Release/  obj/sse42.stamp" exited with code 1.  sse42   C:\Users\Me\Documents\skia\out\Release\obj\sse42.vcxproj    64  
Error       opening build log: Permission denied    ssse3   C:\Users\Me\Documents\skia\out\Release\obj\ninja    1   
Error   MSB3073 The command "call ninja.exe -C ../../../out/Release/  obj/ssse3.stamp" exited with code 1.  ssse3   C:\Users\Me\Documents\skia\out\Release\obj\ssse3.vcxproj    69  
Error       opening build log: Permission denied    tests ((skia)\tests)    C:\Users\Me\Documents\skia\out\Release\obj\ninja    1   
Error   MSB3073 The command "call ninja.exe -C ../../../out/Release/  obj/tests.stamp" exited with code 1.  tests ((skia)\tests)    C:\Users\Me\Documents\skia\out\Release\obj\tests.vcxproj    1405    
Error   MSB3073 The command "call ninja.exe -C ../../../out/Release/  ./lua_app.exe" exited with code 1.    lua_app C:\Users\Me\Documents\skia\out\Release\obj\lua_app.vcxproj  66  
Error       opening build log: Permission denied    Nima-Cpp    C:\Users\Me\Documents\skia\out\Release\obj\third_party\Nima-Cpp\ninja   1   
Error   MSB3073 The command "call ninja.exe -C ../../../../../out/Release/  obj/third_party/Nima-Cpp/Nima-Cpp.stamp" exited with code 1.    Nima-Cpp    C:\Users\Me\Documents\skia\out\Release\obj\third_party\Nima-Cpp\Nima-Cpp.vcxproj    234 
Error       opening build log: Permission denied    expat   C:\Users\Me\Documents\skia\out\Release\obj\third_party\expat\ninja  1   
Error       opening build log: Permission denied    harfbuzz    C:\Users\Me\Documents\skia\out\Release\obj\third_party\harfbuzz\ninja   1   
Error   MSB3073 The command "call ninja.exe -C ../../../../../out/Release/  obj/third_party/expat/expat.stamp" exited with code 1.  expat   C:\Users\Me\Documents\skia\out\Release\obj\third_party\expat\expat.vcxproj  70  
Error   MSB3073 The command "call ninja.exe -C ../../../../../out/Release/  obj/third_party/harfbuzz/harfbuzz.stamp" exited with code 1.    harfbuzz    C:\Users\Me\Documents\skia\out\Release\obj\third_party\harfbuzz\harfbuzz.vcxproj    190 
Error       opening build log: Permission denied    icu C:\Users\Me\Documents\skia\out\Release\obj\third_party\icu\ninja    1   
Error   MSB3073 The command "call ninja.exe -C ../../../../../out/Release/  obj/third_party/icu/icu.stamp" exited with code 1.  icu C:\Users\Me\Documents\skia\out\Release\obj\third_party\icu\icu.vcxproj  782 
Error       opening build log: Permission denied    imgui   C:\Users\Me\Documents\skia\out\Release\obj\third_party\imgui\ninja  1   
Error   MSB3073 The command "call ninja.exe -C ../../../../../out/Release/  obj/third_party/imgui/imgui.stamp" exited with code 1.  imgui   C:\Users\Me\Documents\skia\out\Release\obj\third_party\imgui\imgui.vcxproj  70  
Error       opening build log: Permission denied    jsoncpp C:\Users\Me\Documents\skia\out\Release\obj\third_party\jsoncpp\ninja    1   
Error   MSB3073 The command "call ninja.exe -C ../../../../../out/Release/  obj/third_party/jsoncpp/jsoncpp.stamp" exited with code 1.  jsoncpp C:\Users\Me\Documents\skia\out\Release\obj\third_party\jsoncpp\jsoncpp.vcxproj  70  
Error       opening build log: Permission denied    libjpeg C:\Users\Me\Documents\skia\out\Release\obj\third_party\libjpeg-turbo\ninja  1   
Error   MSB3073 The command "call ninja.exe -C ../../../../../out/Release/  obj/third_party/libjpeg-turbo/libjpeg.stamp" exited with code 1.    libjpeg C:\Users\Me\Documents\skia\out\Release\obj\third_party\libjpeg-turbo\libjpeg.vcxproj    242 
Error       opening build log: Permission denied    libmicrohttpd   C:\Users\Me\Documents\skia\out\Release\obj\third_party\libmicrohttpd\ninja  1   
Error       opening build log: Permission denied    libpng  C:\Users\Me\Documents\skia\out\Release\obj\third_party\libpng\ninja 1   
Error   MSB3073 The command "call ninja.exe -C ../../../../../out/Release/  obj/third_party/libmicrohttpd/libmicrohttpd.stamp" exited with code 1.  libmicrohttpd   C:\Users\Me\Documents\skia\out\Release\obj\third_party\libmicrohttpd\libmicrohttpd.vcxproj  98  
Error   MSB3073 The command "call ninja.exe -C ../../../../../out/Release/  obj/third_party/libpng/libpng.stamp" exited with code 1.    libpng  C:\Users\Me\Documents\skia\out\Release\obj\third_party\libpng\libpng.vcxproj    126 
Error       opening build log: Permission denied    libwebp C:\Users\Me\Documents\skia\out\Release\obj\third_party\libwebp\ninja    1   
Error       opening build log: Permission denied    libwebp_avx2    C:\Users\Me\Documents\skia\out\Release\obj\third_party\libwebp\ninja    1   
Error   MSB3073 The command "call ninja.exe -C ../../../../../out/Release/  obj/third_party/libwebp/libwebp.stamp" exited with code 1.  libwebp C:\Users\Me\Documents\skia\out\Release\obj\third_party\libwebp\libwebp.vcxproj  490 
Error   MSB3073 The command "call ninja.exe -C ../../../../../out/Release/  obj/third_party/libwebp/libwebp_avx2.stamp" exited with code 1. libwebp_avx2    C:\Users\Me\Documents\skia\out\Release\obj\third_party\libwebp\libwebp_avx2.vcxproj 62  
Error       opening build log: Permission denied    lua ((skia)\(third_party)\(lua)\lua)    C:\Users\Me\Documents\skia\out\Release\obj\third_party\lua\ninja    1   
Error   MSB3073 The command "call ninja.exe -C ../../../../../out/Release/  obj/third_party/lua/lua.stamp" exited with code 1.  lua ((skia)\(third_party)\(lua)\lua)    C:\Users\Me\Documents\skia\out\Release\obj\third_party\lua\lua.vcxproj  190 
Error       opening build log: Permission denied    libwebp_sse41   C:\Users\Me\Documents\skia\out\Release\obj\third_party\libwebp\ninja    1   
Error   MSB3073 The command "call ninja.exe -C ../../../../../out/Release/  obj/third_party/libwebp/libwebp_sse41.stamp" exited with code 1.    libwebp_sse41   C:\Users\Me\Documents\skia\out\Release\obj\third_party\libwebp\libwebp_sse41.vcxproj    74  
Error       opening build log: Permission denied    zlib    C:\Users\Me\Documents\skia\out\Release\obj\third_party\zlib\ninja   1   
Error   MSB3073 The command "call ninja.exe -C ../../../../../out/Release/  obj/third_party/zlib/zlib.stamp" exited with code 1.    zlib    C:\Users\Me\Documents\skia\out\Release\obj\third_party\zlib\zlib.vcxproj    118 
Error       opening build log: Permission denied    zlib_x86    C:\Users\Me\Documents\skia\out\Release\obj\third_party\zlib\ninja   1   
Error   MSB3073 The command "call ninja.exe -C ../../../../../out/Release/  obj/third_party/zlib/zlib_x86.stamp" exited with code 1.    zlib_x86    C:\Users\Me\Documents\skia\out\Release\obj\third_party\zlib\zlib_x86.vcxproj    70  
Error       opening build log: Permission denied    tool_utils  C:\Users\Me\Documents\skia\out\Release\obj\ninja    1   
Error   MSB3073 The command "call ninja.exe -C ../../../out/Release/  obj/tool_utils.stamp" exited with code 1. tool_utils  C:\Users\Me\Documents\skia\out\Release\obj\tool_utils.vcxproj   156 
Error       opening build log: Permission denied    typeface_freetype   C:\Users\Me\Documents\skia\out\Release\obj\ninja    1   
Error   MSB3073 The command "call ninja.exe -C ../../../out/Release/  obj/typeface_freetype.stamp" exited with code 1.  typeface_freetype   C:\Users\Me\Documents\skia\out\Release\obj\typeface_freetype.vcxproj    59  
Error       opening build log: Permission denied    viewer  C:\Users\Me\Documents\skia\out\Release\obj\ninja    1   
Error   MSB3073 The command "call ninja.exe -C ../../../out/Release/  ./viewer.exe" exited with code 1. viewer  C:\Users\Me\Documents\skia\out\Release\obj\viewer.vcxproj   115 
Error       opening build log: Permission denied    webp    C:\Users\Me\Documents\skia\out\Release\obj\ninja    1   
Error   MSB3073 The command "call ninja.exe -C ../../../out/Release/  obj/webp.stamp" exited with code 1.   webp    C:\Users\Me\Documents\skia\out\Release\obj\webp.vcxproj 72  
Error       opening build log: Permission denied    wuffs   C:\Users\Me\Documents\skia\out\Release\obj\ninja    1   
Error   MSB3073 The command "call ninja.exe -C ../../../out/Release/  obj/wuffs.stamp" exited with code 1.  wuffs   C:\Users\Me\Documents\skia\out\Release\obj\wuffs.vcxproj    59  
Error       opening build log: Permission denied    xml C:\Users\Me\Documents\skia\out\Release\obj\ninja    1   
Error   MSB3073 The command "call ninja.exe -C ../../../out/Release/  obj/xml.stamp" exited with code 1.    xml C:\Users\Me\Documents\skia\out\Release\obj\xml.vcxproj  80  
Error   C1083   Cannot open compiler generated file: 'C:\Users\Me\Documents\skia\out\Release\obj\src\gpu\effects\gpu.GrPorterDuffXferProcessor.obj': Permission denied  samples ((skia)\samples)    C:\Users\Me\Documents\skia\src\gpu\effects\GrPorterDuffXferProcessor.cpp    1   
Error   MSB3073 The command "call ninja.exe -C ../../../out/Release/  obj/samples.stamp" exited with code 1.    samples ((skia)\samples)    C:\Users\Me\Documents\skia\out\Release\obj\samples.vcxproj  454 
Error   C1083   Cannot open compiler generated file: 'C:\Users\Me\Documents\skia\out\Release\obj\src\pathops\skia.SkPathWriter.obj': Permission denied  Mech    C:\Users\Me\Documents\skia\src\pathops\SkPathWriter.cpp 1   
Error   LNK1104 cannot open file 'obj\src\utils\skia.SkNWayCanvas.obj'  fuzz ((skia)\(modules)\(skottie)\fuzz)  C:\Users\Me\Documents\skia\out\Release\obj\modules\skottie\LINK 1   
Error   MSB3073 The command "call ninja.exe -C ../../../../../out/Release/  obj/modules/skottie/fuzz.stamp" exited with code 1. fuzz ((skia)\(modules)\(skottie)\fuzz)  C:\Users\Me\Documents\skia\out\Release\obj\modules\skottie\fuzz.vcxproj 64  
Error   MSB3073 The command "call ninja.exe -C ../../../out/Release/  obj/Mech.stamp" exited with code 1.   Mech    C:\Users\Me\Documents\skia\out\Release\obj\Mech.vcxproj 536 
Error   LNK1104 cannot open file 'obj\src\pdf\pdf.SkPDFDevice.obj'  tests ((skia)\(modules)\(sksg)\tests)   C:\Users\Me\Documents\skia\out\Release\obj\modules\sksg\LINK    1   
Error   MSB3073 The command "call ninja.exe -C ../../../../../out/Release/  obj/modules/sksg/tests.stamp" exited with code 1.   tests ((skia)\(modules)\(sksg)\tests)   C:\Users\Me\Documents\skia\out\Release\obj\modules\sksg\tests.vcxproj   64  
Error   C1083   Cannot open compiler generated file: 'C:\Users\Me\Documents\skia\out\Release\obj\src\ports\skia.SkFontMgr_win_dw.obj': Permission denied    skiaserve   C:\Users\Me\Documents\skia\src\ports\SkFontMgr_win_dw.cpp   1   
Error   MSB3073 The command "call ninja.exe -C ../../../out/Release/  ./skiaserve.exe" exited with code 1.  skiaserve   C:\Users\Me\Documents\skia\out\Release\obj\skiaserve.vcxproj    134
```

Comment: You can get help here from experienced programmers that know what these build errors actually mean.  But if you don't share them then they can't help you.

Comment: Thanks, Hans. I'm getting many different errors, depending on how I try to link the lib, or my starting template. I think if I were to try to post every error here, it may be inefficient for all involved. I'm looking for info on how to set a Skia project up in the first place.

Comment: Hans, I have updated the question, per your advice. There are also a series of "premature end of file; recovering" warnings. 

From some guesswork & searching, it seems possible that the build order is a problem, though I know of no way to determine what the dependencies are.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest not building from the visual studio ide. Building using ninja directly should work fine (I just tried it).

These two commands should do it for you:

```
gn gen out\Release
ninja -C out\Release
```

Answer (score 0):

For visual studio build first, you have to create a solution file for that.
Please follow these procedures and then you will build with visual studio.

- Install Python 2.7+
- Install Git
- Install Visual Studio
- Download the dependency tools `depot_tools`, please follow this [link](https://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/chrome-infra-docs/flat/depot_tools/docs/html/depot_tools_tutorial.html#_setting_up)
- Add the path to the PC's environment and it must be before any python path.
- Download the Skia source code `git clone https://skia.googlesource.com/skia.git`
- Enter the source directory of skia `cd D:/skia`
- Execute the python script `python tools/git-sync-deps`
- Set your VC toolset to the build configuration file
- Open the skia/gn/BUILDCONFIG.gn file with Notpad++
- Set the value of win_vc = "" to the VC directory in your VisualStudio installation directory. (The path of each computer is different)
  Like my settings:`win_vc = "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Enterprise\VC"`
- Execute for Visual Studio solution file

```
## Execute in the skia directory -> skia\bin
## Directly build Visual Studio's .sln file
> gn gen out/sln --ide=vs
```

Now you get the solution file for Visual Studio and then build with Visual Studio.